# How to verify an input in a constexpr function

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have a constexpr function, and I want to verify something about the input.
As all is done at compile time - It seems possible for the verification be done too at compilation time:

```
constexpr int half(int n)
{
    static_assert(n>100); // error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    if constexpr (n>100) grouch(); //  error: ‘n’ is not a constant expression
    return n>>1;
}
```

how can I make this verification at compile time?

Comment: If I recall correctly throwing in a const-expr function aborts compilation if evaluated at compile time.

Comment: I think you can use template metaprogramming techniques!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare functions as `consteval` and trigger non-constant expressions such as throwing exceptions or calling non-`constexpr` functions when conditions are not satisfied

```
#include <stdexcept>

consteval int half(int n)
{
  if (n <= 100)
    throw std::invalid_argument("n must be greater than 100");
  return n >> 1;
}
```